# Device ID in Windows Phone 10

Tags: windows-phone

I'm looking to get the unique Device ID of a Windows Phone 10 Handset - I'm doing some BLE work, and when the phone receives a packet, I want it to send the Device ID back to the beacon.

I've looked at the Device.getextendedproperties API but it isn't available in Windows 10.

Cheers